# how could I create restriction in input when input is 100 above

Tags: python, exception, input

There are I have two problem please help
problem 1 - input should be integer 1-100 `rand_num = random.randint(1,100)` if input goes 100 above then show enter valid number 1 to 100 how could I achieve this please help

Thanks!

and also Could please give me a  another suggestion to make my project more better.

```
import random 

LIVES = 10
SCORE = 0
HIGH_SCORE = 0

print("\t\t =============>  Welcome to the number guessing game developed by Python  <===============\n")
print("You have only 10 lives to guessing the number\n\
    ")

rand_num = random.randint(1,100)
print(rand_num)
while LIVES >=0:
    try:
        user = int(input("Choose a number between 1-100 : "))
        if user == rand_num:
            print("Congratulations You guessed it right.")
            SCORE=11-LIVES
            if SCORE > SCORE:
                SCORE += HIGH_SCORE
            print(f"Your score is {SCORE} ")
            print(f"The Score Is {HIGH_SCORE}")
            break
        elif user > rand_num:
            LIVES-=1
            print(f"Too high! Please guess lower number.\n Current Lives= {LIVES}")
        elif user < rand_num:
            LIVES-=1
            print(f"Too Low! Please guess higher number.\n Current Lives= {LIVES}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. I gave you a duplicate for the first question.

Comment: hey bro its not same it's please help I asked how I can restricted input between 1 to 100

Comment: Why isn't it the same? That question show how to repeat a question until the answer meets a condition. In your case, the condition is that the input is between 1 and 100.

Comment: No I changed the title please see again and help If you can.

Comment: The new title doesn't change anything. The condition for the input is still `1 <= int(input) <= 100`

Comment: I am very new to stack overrflow nothing know please do cancel duplicate after that I will remove this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a few embellishments to your code so that it could be played more than once.

```
import random 

LIVES = 10
SCORE = 0
HIGH_SCORE = 0
DONE = False

print("\t\t =============>  Welcome to the number guessing game developed by Python  <===============\n")
print("You have only 10 lives to guessing the number\n")

rand_num = int(random.randint(1,100))
print(rand_num)

while True:
    while LIVES >=0:
        try:
            user_string = input("Choose a number between 1-100 : ")
            if user_string == "Q" or user_string == "q":
                DONE = True
                break
            user = int(user_string)
            if user > 100 or user < 1:          # To account for invalid guesses
                print("Guesses must be from 1 to 100")
                continue
            if user == rand_num:
                print("Congratulations You guessed it right.")
                SCORE = LIVES
                print(f"Your score is {SCORE} ")
                if SCORE > HIGH_SCORE:
                    print("This is also a new high score!!!")
                    HIGH_SCORE = SCORE
                print(f"The Current High Score Is {HIGH_SCORE}")
                break
            elif user > rand_num:
                LIVES-=1
                print(f"Too high! Please guess lower number.\n Current Lives= {LIVES}")
            elif user < rand_num:
                LIVES-=1
                print(f"Too Low! Please guess higher number.\n Current Lives= {LIVES}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e) 
            
    if (DONE == True):
        break
            
    # Let's do this again    
            
    print("\t\t =============>  Welcome to the number guessing game developed by Python  <===============\n")
    print("You have only 10 lives to guessing the number\n")
    rand_num = int(random.randint(1,100))
    print(rand_num)
    LIVES = 10
    SCORE = 0
```

First off, I ensured that the user input was an integer by wrapping the value inside the "int" function.  Next, per your request, I added a range test of the entered value so that it only allows guesses from "1" to "100".  Then, I also added in another "while" loop to provide for a continuous number of games.  That way, the number of tries could be kept and compared to any previous high score to see if a new high score was achieved.  In order to exit the game and the highest level "while" loop a test is made to see if the user has entered "Q" or "q" to quit (you might want to add verbiage to the program to direct the user).

Anyway, try those out and see if that is close to what your are trying to accomplish.

Comment: hey bro thanks a lot you did as I was wanting